# Greater than or Smaller than within array_walk recursive

Tags: php, arrays, array-walk

I am trying to replace `array` value with specific condition.

Suppose array `$mark` has following value

```
$mark = array(90,85);
```

Just normal checking value it is echoing correct value

```
array_walk_recursive($mark, function (&$k) { 
  if($k==90){$k='4.0';}
  if($k==85){$k='3.6';}
});

print_r($mark);
```

**Output is**

```
Array ( [0] => 4.0 [1] => 3.6 )
```

But while applying condition such as greater than or less than, it returns wrong value.

```
array_walk_recursive($mark, function (&$k) { 
  if($k>=90){$k='4.0';}
  if($k>=80 AND $k<90){$k='3.6';}
  if($k<79){$k='2.8';}
});

print_r($mark);
```

And the **Output** is

```
Array ( [0] => 2.8 [1] => 2.8 )
```

Comment: Because `if($k<79){$k='2.8';}` always __true__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `else` in `if`

```
<?php
$mark = array(90,85);

array_walk_recursive($mark, function (&$k) { 
    if ($k >= 90) {
        $k = '4.0';
    } else if ($k >= 80 && $k<90) {
        $k = '3.6';
    } else if ($k < 80) {
        $k = '2.8';
    }
});

print_r($mark);
```

See it in action on [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/I6L1L)

Answer (score 3):

Each `if` is testing the value after the previous one may have already changed the value.

When `$k` is 90, the first `if` succeeds, which changes it to `4.0`.

The second `if` fails because `4.0` is not between `80` and `90`.

The third `if` succeeds because `4.0` is less than `79`, so it changes it to `2.8`.

You should use `elseif` so it only performs the tests when the previous one failed, and then it will always be testing the original value of `$k`. You can also use `else` for the last case.

```
array_walk_recursive($mark, function (&$k) { 
        if($k>=90) {
            $k='4.0';
        }
        elseif($k>=80 AND $k<90) {
            $k='3.6';
        }
        elseif($k<79) {
            $k='2.8';
        }
    });
```

BTW, you probably wanted to use `< 80` for the last test, or just `else` with no test. When `$k` is exactly `79`, you won't update it.

Answer (score 2):

Every `if` in your function is checked in order it appears in code:

```
// $k is 90
if($k>=90){$k='4.0';}
// $k is 4
if($k>=80 AND $k<90){$k='3.6';}
// $k is still 4
if($k<79){$k='2.8';}
// $k is 2.8
```

Use `if-elseif-else` instead:

```
if ($k>=90) {
    $k='4.0';
} elseif ($k>=80 AND $k<90){
    $k='3.6';
} else {
    $k='2.8';
}
```